# Передача GET запроса в php (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

Здравствуйте.
Возникла проблема, не получается использовать GET запрос в этой части кода (при нажатии на ссылку должно переводить на страницу site.ru/lesson.php?id=1, но открывает страницу ошибки(т.е. включается функция not_found()))

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `lessons` WHERE `teachid` = '".$_SESSION['id']."' ");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $haslesson = TRUE;
    echo "
        <br>
        <a href='lesson.php?id=".$row['id']."'><p>".$row['title']."</p></a><br>
    ";
}
```

Как я сам предполагаю, скорее всего дело в .htaccess, или же в моем index.php

**.htaccess:**

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Часть кода **index.php**, в которой тоже нужно что-то исправить

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') $page ='home';
else
{
    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    if(!preg_match('/^[A-z0-9]{3,40}$/', $page) ) not_found();
}

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'qschool');

if (!$connect)
{
    exit('MySQL error');
}

session_start();
if ( file_exists('all/'.$page.'.php')) include 'all/'.$page.'.php';

else if ( $_SESSION['id'] and file_exists('auth/'.$page.'.php')) include 'auth/'.$page.'.php';

else if ( !$_SESSION['id'] and file_exists('guest/'.$page.'.php')) include 'guest/'.$page.'.php';

else not_found();
```

Знаю, что подобных вопросов здесь полно, но все мои попытки оказались тщетными.
 Надеюсь на помощь. Спасибо
*P.S. Я почти уверен, что нужно поменять preg_match и добавить что-то в .htaccess*

Comment: а что дебаг показывает?

Comment: а вот это ваше где? "не получается использовать GET запрос" У вас вроде в `sq` стоит Супер Глобальная переменная СЕССИИ

Comment: Извини, не до конца понимаю что имеешь ввиду под "дебаг".. 
 Консоль браузера ошибки не показывает

Comment: Должно переводить на site.ru/lesson.php?id=1

Comment: @D.Joe ты при разработке IDE используешь? или в блокноте пишешь? Если исп. IDE то твой код можно запустить и проверить как и что работает, какие переменные назначены и что вообще в целом происходит внутри твоего кода. Там же можно посмотреть что приходит  в код из глобальных массивов.

Comment: @N. Turshiev, пишу в sublime text
Работать все должно правильно. Просто у меня сделано так, что если в конце ссылки добавить ".php", то будет ошибка. А как раз таки для передачи GET запроса это ".php" и нужно..

Answer (score 1):

В .htaccess замените

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

на

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

В index.php

```
$page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
if(!preg_match('/^[A-z0-9]{3,40}$/', $page) ) not_found();
```

на

```
if (preg_match('/^\/([a-z0-9]{3,40})(\?.*)?$/i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)) {
    $page = $matches[1];
} else {
    not_found();
}
```

Comment: Помогло! 
Огромное вам спасибо)